# How can we set python package version in setup.py programmatically in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: python, pip, azure-pipelines

I am trying to automate the build/deploy aspect of our python library, but am unable to figure out how to programmatically set the version number so that the version number updates with every build. I even tried to find some pip commands that might help in doing this but no luck. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe pbr will work for you? It takes version number from git: https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html#version

Comment: @psarka Is there no pip command to build the package with a new version

Answer (score 1):

Create a setup.py file like this to be able to call it with custom version argument:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

####### get version from arguments start ##########
index = sys.argv.index('--version')
sys.argv.pop(index)
version = sys.argv.pop(index)
####### get version from arguments end ##########

DESCRIPTION = 'short description'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'long description'
# Setting up
setup(
        name="package name", 
        version=version,
        author="your name",
        description=DESCRIPTION,
        long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
        packages=find_packages(),
        install_requires=[], 
        keywords=['python'],
        classifiers= [
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
        ]
)
```

now you can build the package with using the version argument:

```
python setup.py --version 0.1.1 sdist bdist_wheel
```

add versionNumber variable to azure-pipeline.yaml and increase as you wish:

```
variables:
  majorMinorVersion: 1.0
  # semanticVersion counter is automatically incremented by one in each execution of pipeline
  # second parameter is seed value to reset to every time the referenced majorMinorVersion is changed
  semanticVersion: $[counter(variables['majorMinorVersion'], 0)]
  versionNumber: '$(majorMinorVersion).$(semanticVersion)'
```

and add this command as well to azure-pipeline.yaml to create the build:

```
- script: python setup.py --version $(versionNumber) bdist_wheel
  displayName: 'Artifact creation'
```